# embedding three.js in Colab

Tags: javascript, python, three.js, fetch, google-colaboratory

These are some examples of bi-directional communications between python and javascript on Google Colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb

How can I get this simple three.js demo working in Colab?
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_lines.html

The source code seems really simple, but I can't get it working in Colab.

Can we also send updated BufferGeometry data (efficiently, in binary form) from python numpy array to three.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the main part that I change

```
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three?module';
//import Stats from './jsm/libs/stats.module.js';
```

I import THREE from unpkg, and remove the Stats part.

Here's a [working notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nrK1bg8rqoYGVZfd4cuB3ndFvuUafVuu).

### JS calling Python

If you need to get data in THREE from Python, there are 2 difficult ways.

1. invokeFunction: see these [3 examples](https://gist.github.com/search?q=user%3Akorakot+invokeFunction). The limitation is that you can pass only JSON data.
2. proxyPort API: see [this solution](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/blois/97efe8fc938fe4055e2263514ec32065/copy-of-three-js-http-server-demo.ipynb) by @blois and my [simplification](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11NkxN6TYZHHS26h8OBEdiovQb4S0oKGf). You need to start a web server. You can serve binary data by giving a `content-length` header, as [discussed here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/pythreejs/issues/317#issuecomment-606089696). Use `fetch` and `arrayBuffer` on the receiving end.  Currently, this solution seems to not work with Firefox, but it works with Chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That looks very nice!  Two questions: first, why do we use unpkg.com?  Second, how do we call python and get a numpy array back for three.js to use?

Comment: Unpkg support "module import" from url. You can try it with other CDNs, or download and serve directly from colab. To call Python from JS, you need to use `invokeFunction`. Some examples here https://gist.github.com/search?q=user%3Akorakot+invokeFunction

Comment: How can we get efficient binary numpy transfers instead of Json?  I didn't see any documentation for invokeFunction that explains that.  Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't. invokeFunction is already advanced, you can hardly find any doc on it. I need to experiment myself. 

Please also accept my answer.

Comment: Korakot, your answer was very valuable and helped us find a full binary solution.  See blois'es answer: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/pythreejs/issues/317#issuecomment-606089696

Can you link to the solution from blois?  Or I can link to it myself.  Add invokeFunction.

For some use cases, binary transfer is very important: imagine a Tensorflow model that gradually morphs faces from young to old, for example.  You cannot use JSON for that.  Binary is just more efficient.  The answer from blois appears to work well and addresses that. I'll accept your answer after edit/mod. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the answer. Thanks for your quest to find the solution. I've always wanted to know how to do difficult things in Colab. And our final solution have expanded the boundary. Thanks!!

Comment: Here's simplified version of @blois's answer. Loading any numpy variable using request's path. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11NkxN6TYZHHS26h8OBEdiovQb4S0oKGf

Comment: Many thanks Korakot!  I really appreciate your answer.  I still added a very minor edit to your answer to indicate that fetch seems to not work in Firefox, but it works in Chrome.  It might also be a good idea to copy all the information from the links into this answer directly, just to make sure it's all here.  That would make the answer a bit longer.  Maybe we can consider doing that later on.

Comment: "Here's simplified version of @blois's answer. Loading any numpy variable using request's path. … – Korakot Chaovavanich"

This is very valuable in it's own right, and can be added to the main answer.